# Automatically Increasing the KMS requests in all AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-billing

I have an AWS account where I used only N.Virginia and Ohio region for my works.

But, when I go to the billing dashboard, I have seen, there are also request in other regions for KMS. I have attached the image screenshot for the reference:

[image]

It is not costing me the money, but I want to know how these requests incurred.

How can I find this out?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing, are you under consolidated billing account and this might be activities on different account? Do you have any other services besides KMS that are deployed in those regions (maybe using a key?)? Check your EC2 cost on the same page - does it specifies those regions? Any more information you can share?

Comment: Yes, My master account is another account. I am just using the master account for consolidated billing.  And, coming to the EC2 part, I am using ec2 only in N.Virginia region and there are no other regions included in the billing for ec2. @Dvir669